# Como atualizar chart automaticamente a cada 60 segundos?

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Tenho um projeto onde preciso atualizar um *form* a cada 60 segundos, sendo que no form existe uma função para chamar o chart (gráfico) e quando executo o programa o form  inicializa perfeitamente o gráfico porém quando uso o *timer* chamando a função novamente para atualizar a página o gráfico não atualiza e dar uma mensagem de erro:

> Não foi possível encontrar um elemento de gráfico com o nome `Series1` em SeriesCollection'. Segue a função:

```
DIM SQL AS STRING 
SQL = SELECT TELE_MARKENTIG, VENDEDOR, TOTAL FROM PEDIDOS

Dim CArea As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
Dim LG As Legend = New Legend()
Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)
 CArea.Name = "ChartArea20"
 Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(CArea)
 ''Legend1.Name = "Legend20"
Chart1.Legends.Add(LG)
 Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
Chart1.Name = "Chart12"
Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea20"
 ''Series1.Legend = "Legend20"
 Series1.Name = "Vendas"
 Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
 Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(300, 175)
'chtVendas.TabIndex = 0
'chtVendas.Text = "Chart1"
CArea.Position.Width = 75
CArea.Position.Height = 100

Chart1.Series("Vendas").XValueMember = "TELE_MARKETING"
Chart1.Series("Vendas").YValueMembers = "TOTAL"
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim DATAADAPTER As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL, CN)

DATAADAPTER.Fill(ds, "VCTCS")


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'~~> SET DATA SOURCE <~~'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("VCTCS")

Chart1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver o erro:

> Não foi possível encontrar um elemento de gráfico com o nome Series1 em SeriesCollection'.

Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
Chart1.Series.Remove(series1)
```

Ou seja, antes de chamar o `chart` precisava removê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Mova as seguintes declaraçõees do método para a classe.  Muito provavelmente os objetos estao sendo descartados antes do **timer** ser executado, e movendo eles para a classe irá evitar que isso aconteça.

```
Private CArea As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
Private LG As Legend = New Legend()
Private Series1 As Series = New Series()
Private Chart1 = New Chart()
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar.
Analisando bem o erro verifiquei que tinha que remover o chart para solucionar o problema e utilizei o seguinte código:
Chart1.Series.Remove(series1)

Comment: @rogerio.engineer você achou sua própria solução? Poste ela como uma resposta e aceite ela. Isso pode até ajudar você ganhar reputação e deixar destacado para outras pessoas.

Comment: valeu. obrigado.
conseguir sim.